# How to make it so i can only mine a part when i have a specific tool in my hand? (Roblox Studio)

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

I am making a mining game on roblox and i need a mechanism where i can mine ore only when i have a pickaxe equipped and i want it to play a animation and sound when i am mining. I am fairly new to scripting in roblox.  I mostly have done models but decided to make this game.  Here's the code i made to get it started.  I have some variables assigned such as the tool and animations.

```
tool = script.Parent

local r6anim = game.StarterPack.Pickaxe["Pickaxe Anim R6"]

local r15anim = game.StarterPack.Pickaxe["Pickaxe Anim R15"]

tool.Activated:Connect(function()

end)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late but here goes

U wanna have a localscript in ur tool and a normal script in serverscriptservice call them anything u want

Next step make a remote inside of replicated storage name this something easy to remember

The logic here is when a player equips the pickaxe tool u can set a var = true allowing them to mine as long as u have it equiped u can do that with the tool.equiped:connect(function) and when u unequip it do tool.unequiped etc

Make a var referencing ur remote u made earlier by doing local myremotething = game:getservice("replicatedstorage").remotenamehere

Then inside of ur tool.activated func u wanna do 
Myremotething:FireServer()

Then u can code the server ens to handle all ur animations and setup stuff thats the general way to do it i will make a test game later today and reply to u sry for vague answer im on mobile lolol

Comment: thank you. a little vague but thanks for the help.  ill try it out.  also bonus for fe compatible  version.